# Dictionary of English constructions

Tags: online-resources

There is a family of grammars called [construction grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_grammar) that started perhaps in the 80s with the work of Fillmore & Kay among others. Examples of constructions include:

1. the time + *away* construction (*they danced the night away*)
2. the *way* construction (*he glad handed his way into the club*)
3. the incredulity construction (*Bush, a humanitarian!?*)

I'm wondering if there is a dictionary or list of these constructions. I'm not looking for something exhaustive, but fairly extensive. Various online searches have turned up only a Japanese dictionary *The Taishukan Contemporary Dictionary of English Constructions*, but judging from the Japanese title 〈最新〉英語構文事典, I would say it's unlikely to be what I'm after.

Comment: Constructions of the kind Fillmore and Kay talk about don't lend themselves to a dictionary approach, since each one has complex syntactic, semantic, and pragmatic affordances that require more than a list to explicate. Another example is [the paper by Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor on the *let alone* construction](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/fillmore%2B88.pdf). But in many ways what you want is [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu), which is organized around the frames (cultural, pragmatic, interactional, semantic) that these constructions are used in.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources

Comment: There's also the [list of syntactic rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) (most of which create constructions) from Haj Ross, and the list of [verb classes involved in governed cyclic alternations](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/levin.verbs2.txt) from Levin.

Comment: Thanks, John! I know what you mean about not lending themselves to a dictionary approach. Perhaps list would be a better description. I've read Fillmore, Kay, & O'Connor and I'm aware of Framenet. They're both useful, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: That list from Ross is more like what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This question may be off-topic, and use terminology in a way that might confuse, but one wouldn't complain about the links provided.

Comment: I would be careful with such constructions.  They're often colloquial, and if a non-native speaker uses them, it can be somewhat humorous.  I had an exchange student live with my family when I was in high school.  He loved learning these constructions / colloquialisms, but it was quite funny listening to him master them, because the change of a single word often changes the meaning of these colloquialisms.

Comment: That's true, it is colloquial. That is, it's real English. Colloquial English means English as it's spoken, which is the real language. What's sometimes called "formal English" is simply stuffy, an attempt to talk like our betters.

Comment: Formal English isn't stuffy at all. It's just more proper. There's lots of good reasons to use formal English.

Comment: In context, there's nothing wrong with Formal English. People who insist (or pretend to insist) that anything else is "wrong" or "improper", and that it should be used in all circumstances have no understanding of how language works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a question for [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) (that is, though the examples are in English, and the request is for patterns in English, it is most likely not restricted to English, and more likely that someone at Ling.SE would know).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (even though it is 'too old to migrate' a request for resources belongs on meta.